# Resetting a field to its default value

Tags: dojo

I want to be able to reset all text fields to their default values when a button is clicked.

What I've done so far is query for all text fields and bind a function I wrote called 'textChanged' to the change event as follows:

```
require(["dojo/on","dojo/query"], function(on,query){
    query(".Text").on("change",textChanged);
});
```

The function is defined as follows:

```
function textChanged(newVal)
{
...
}
```

I found I can reset the value in the body of the function by doing the assignment:

```
   newVal.target.value = newVal.target.defaultValue;
```

If this function is triggered by a change event.

What I want to do is if a button is clicked, then I want to execute the newVal.target.value = newVal.target.defaultValue and am having trouble getting the context correct.

I've tried preserving the 'this' variable when it is called as well as preserving the 'newVal' parameter.  If I try setting the value outside of the the context, then the update doesn't preserve.  I've tried setting the 'this' value to some other value (nt = this) and the newValue to another variable (nv = newValue) and then I want to execute:
nv.target.value = nv.target.defaultValue; 
and although it clears the field on the form, when the form is submitted, its actual value is still the manually modified value.  I noticed that the 'this' is different from when I textChanged is called from the change event verses when I call it directly in my button clicked context.

I tried calling it using 'hitch' to set the context of this to its value that it had from the change event, but that doesn't seem to set the correct context:

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/_base/lang"], function(on, lang) {
        lang.hitch(nt, textChanged(nv));
});
```

To be precise - inside textChanged I display the value of 'this' using console.log(this);
When textChanged is invoked when the text changes from the UI, 'this' is:

Yet when it is invoked from clicking my button that calls it via the

```
lang.hitch(nt, textChanged(nv));
```

'this' is: 
Window fauxRedirect.lsw?applicationInstanceId=guid%3A1eae6af09bf6f543%3A-6644aeb4%3A13a8a4c429e%3A-7ffe&zWorkflowState=2&zTaskId=p1&applicationId=2&zComponentName=CoachNG&zComponentId=3028.b1094dc3-da2b-461a-8d56-f6444891c174&zDbg=2#%20%20

I've confirmed that 'nt' is indeed the same '

So, I'm trying to execute the textChanged function such that 'this' is set to that value.

Or, if there is a better way to reset a field to its default from another control - that would work as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure of the full context of what you are trying to do, so don't know if this answers your question?

You can reset all of the widgets within a form to their default value as long as they are wrapped in a *dijit/form/Form* widget. If all the widgets are wrapped correctly it should be a simple matter of calling **reset()** on the form.

**NB:**  This will not work for native elements (ie. standard <input> or <textarea> fields, they must be dijit/form/TextBox ...etc).

eg:

```
<form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" data-dojo-id="theForm">
    <label for="field1">Field 1:</label>
    <input
        type="text" id="field1" name="field1" 
        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" value="default1"
    /><br />

    <label for="field2">Field 1:</label>
    <input
        type="text" id="field2" name="field2"
        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" value="default2"
    />
    <br /><br />

    <button
        type="button" 
        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" 
        onclick="theForm.reset();"
    >Reset</button>
</form>
```

Clicking the reset button here should reset the fields to: field1="default1" and feield2="default2".

The form is calling each widget's **reset()** method.  If you create your own widgets you need to ensure that their **reset()** method works correctly (as well as the **_getValueAttr()** method for setting their value).

Comment: `reset()` also reset the validator's state. (Fields are not marked as invalid after `reset()` )